# How to get parts of a URL string using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have this URL:

```
var url = "mysite.com/categorias/#tab-cultura/folclore/";
```

now I want to get 2 string from that URL:

**#tab-cultura** and **folclore**

how can I get it using Javascript?

```
url.split('#')[0];
```

It seems this `split` is not the right solution:(

Comment: `url.split('#')[1].split('/')[0] ` for the first and `url.split('#')[1].split('/')[1] ` for second

Comment: yes, you want two strings... but based on what??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Split" can be correct way to approach this. Pls see below

```js
var url = "mysite.com/categorias/#tab-cultura/folclore/";

let [val1, val2] = url.split('#')[1].split('/')

console.log(val1, val2)
```

Comment: Yes it's array destructuring.

Comment: Short form of let val1 = url.split('#')[1].split('/')[0], val2 = let val2= url.split('#')[1].split('/')[1]

Comment: I found an issue if the url is like that: http://abc-dev.totalcommit.com/categorias/#tab-educacao/abs

Comment: oh, not it's fine.

Comment: Yes @creativeartbd it will work fine for your mentioned case as well. All the best Happy Coding!! :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to split your URL by `/` delimiter instead

```js
var url = "mysite.com/categorias/#tab-cultura/folclore/";
var parts = url.split('/');
console.log(parts[2]);
console.log(parts[3]);
```

Also you can use regex if you don't know position of `#` in URL

```js
var url = "mysite.com/categorias/category1/category2/#tab-cultura/folclore/";
var parts = url.match(/(#[^\/]+)\/([^\/]+)/);
console.log(parts[1]);
console.log(parts[2]);
```

Comment: Oh, great. Working fine.

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript’s String.prototype.split function:

```
var url = "mysite.com/categorias/#tab-cultura/folclore/";
var fields = input.split('/');

var first = fields[0];
var second = fields[1];
var third = fields[2];
var fourth = fields[3];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `split('/') like so:`

```js
var url = "mysite.com/categorias/#tab-cultura/folclore/";

let [, ,tabCultura, folclore] = url.split('/');

console.log(tabCultura);
console.log(folclore);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Array.split()` will probably get you what you need — for now, but URLs are inherently quite complicated and you want to make sure the code will function the same way on different servers with variable query parameters etc. It may be more reliable to use built in browser functionality:

```
const hash = new URL("http://example.com/categorias/#tab-cultura/folclore/").hash

// => "#tab-cultura/folclore/"

hash.split('/') 

// => ['#tab-cultura', 'folclore', ''] 

hash.split('/').filter(i=>i)

// => ['#tab-cultura', 'folclore']
```

Note: `new URL()` is not available in IE, but can be [polyfilled](https://github.com/github/url-polyfill).